# Why does ajax request with www work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: frametarget,
        dataType: 'html',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            // $("#result").html(data[0].title);
           console.log(data);
         },
         error: function(error){
              console.log(error);
         }
    });
```

Now if frametarget = "www.skysports.com" the call is a success but using skysports.com the call fails?

I am making cross domain calls for both URLs, so I expected both to fail.

Comment: well, first you would need to know why it failed. Look to your dev tools for clues.

Comment: Any cross-domain call first send OPTIONS request to check if server accepts such request. It seems that www.skysports.com is set to accept but skysports.com not. Maybe there is a permanent redirect from skysports.com to www.skysports.com that causes OPTIONS to fail.

Comment: well, no, only certain cross-domain requests send an OPTIONS request. Changing the url will not impact whether or not it sends an OPTIONS preflight, assuming both www and non www are cross-domain.

Comment: My assumption would be the one that fails is failing because it's trying to redirect, and the redirect response isn't returning proper CORS headers.

Comment: No these are external websites, I have not access to them. @Kevin B -  I am not getting any errors in dev tools, the error handler is called but with now description of the error is given.

Comment: @JD. If this is a CORS problem, you would see an error in your console without the console.log you have in the error callback. Make sure you have errors turned on if you're using firefox. In chrome the error would be pretty obvious direclty in the console by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `http://www.skysports.com` cross domain requests are allowed by this response header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

For `http://skysports.com` there is no CORS header in the response, therefore the browser denies the request.

See [MDN HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more informations.

Comment: So in other words this is a configuration problem with this one specific 3rd party site, right?

Comment: Right. The request `skysports.com` returns a `301` redirect to `www.skysports.com` with no CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks Josa for confirming what others have mentioned.